# How to pass a list of arguments in system execution in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my first experience using rake tasks, but my problem is:
I have a list containing ID's and I want to pass as argument to my rake task. But when I call:

```
url_ids.collect{ |i| i.slice! 'id=' }
system "rake scan_multiple_urls URL_IDS=#{url_ids} &"
```

Rails says:

```
[298486374,
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task '980190962]' (see --tasks)
```

My rake task is this:

```
url_ids = ENV['URL_IDS']
puts url_ids
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = url_ids.collect{ |i| i.slice! 'id=' }
str = arr.join(',')
system "rake scan_multiple_urls URL_IDS=#{str} &"
url_ids = ENV['URL_IDS'].split(',')
puts url_ids
```

Join it as a string and while fetching split it back.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own rake task you have 2 ways to do it

1. rails g task scan_multiple_urls my_task1  create file in
   lib/tasks/scan_multiple_urls.rake
2. it will genereate an file scan_multiple_urls.rake inside lib
   folder

if you open **lib/scan_multiple_urls.rake**

```
namespace :scan_multiple_urls do
  desc "TODO"
  task my_task1: :environment do
     // write your code here
  end

end
```

for example I have list of user ids I need to update all user country to india

```
namespace :my_namespace do
  desc "Update user details Eg: rake my_namespace:my_task1 USER_IDS='1,3,4'"
  task my_task1: :environment do
    user_ids = ENV['USER_IDS'] || ENV['user_ids']
    user_ids = user_ids.split(",") if user_ids.present?
    User.where(id: user_ids).update_all(country: "india")
    p "Update successfull"
  end

end
```

when running the **rake my_namespace:my_task1 USER_IDS='1,3,4'**
all the users country get updated to india

also you can run this by rails console

> arr = url_ids.collect{ |i| i.slice! 'id=' }
> str = arr.join(',')
>
> system "rake my_namespace:my_task1 USER_IDS=#{str} &"